# Send commit in Gitlab thought SSH

Tags: git, gitlab

Create private project in Gitlab. In personal account add public SSH key. When send commit in new empty repository:

```
git push origin master
```

I get error:

```
identity_sign: private key /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa contents do not match public
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The message `private key /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa contents do not match public` tells you what is wrong: something is wrong with your key-pair, in that the private key does not go with the public key.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have registered the public key, it is possible, as described in "[`SSH: identity_sign: private key ~/.ssh/id_rsa contents do not match public`](https://funilrys.com/ssh-private-key-content-do-not-match-public)", that said public key is somehow corrupted (even when the fingerprint matches!?).

You can first and regenerate the public key from the private one:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa >  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

And try to re-register this public key (after deleting your previous public key in your GitHub SSH settings page)

If that fails... delete the public and private key, regenerate a new key pair, and register the new public key.